# Setting attributes in constructor for Django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.8

I have an abstract BaseModel from which many models will inherit the behavior to initialize attributes values from the constructor:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then, I try to initialize one of its specializations like this:

```
BaseModelSon(attr1=val1, attr2=val2, ...)
```

Is this a good practice? Do you know any other way to achieve this dynamic initialization for Django models?

Comment: Did you find a way to initialize the model dynamically from kwargs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already create regular Django model instances with

```
MyModel(field1='value1', field2='value2')
```

so I don't think your `__init__` method is necessary.

Comment: My bad assuming django didn't have this covered

Answer (score 2):

Also you'll probably find useful `Model.objects.create()` method for new Django models instances creation:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(field1='value1', field2='value2'...)
```

If there are some auto-generated fields (for example, id or some date with `auto_now_add=True` option) — you'll get their values in `instance` if you have used `Model.objects.create()`.